# Search results are not displaying on top by relevancy

Tags: 8, search

I have to use **"Search API"** module with configured on solr server and indexed.
The search results are displaying but "relevancy" content is not on top of the page.

**Example #1:**
Search key word: `course in the page`

**Actual Result:**
1) Test `course`
2) Test content `in` shedule `page`
3) Test `page`
4) `Course in the page`

**Expected Result:**
1) `Course in the page`
2) Test `course`
3) Test content `in` shedule `page`
4) Test `page`

Here I need to display first `4) Course in the page` then display others.
I am used views for that search.
 [Views Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYHh8.png) 
Please post your suggestions!

Comment: Hey hey, just noticed you don't ask a question. If it's a bug report please head over to drupal.org and report it there. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I got the answer.
Add the sort criteria `relevance`.
[image]
It's working fine. Cheers!!